# Rescale (0-1; min/max) all columns in a dataframe separately (by column not the whole dataframe)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 300 columns (labeled like so X17.01, X24.05, X200.4...) and 500 rows. I want to rescale those columns to be between 0 and 1 but based on the min/max of each individual column. So, for example, I want to rescale column X17.01 separately from X24.05.

I have used the following codes in R (below) but both rescale the whole data frame.

Code 1:

```
Data_profile_standardized <- data.frame(lapply(Data_profile, function(x) scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/1)))
```

Code 2:

```
normalize <- Vectorize(function(v) (v-min(v))/diff(range(v)))
dfout <- data.frame(normalize(Data_profile_standardize ))
```

Comment: `dfout<-Data_profile; dfout[]<-lapply(dfout, normalize)`

Comment: fixed! Thank you for the support and thorough explanations!

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a nice small test case so we can see what's going on easily:

```
df = data.frame(X1 = 1:3, X2 = c(100, 150, 1000))
```

The problem with `scale` is not that it is applied to the whole data frame, rather it is that with `center = FALSE` all it does is divide by the maximum, so you don't get any 0s:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/1)))
#          X1   X2
# 1 0.3333333 0.10
# 2 0.6666667 0.15
# 3 1.0000000 1.00
```

The problem with your `normalize` function is that it is vectorized as written, and the `Vectorize` is not necessary. Vectorizing it makes it try to normalize each individual entry, not each column, and since the `diff(range())` of a single number is 0, you are dividing by 0 and getting `NaN` as a result:

```
normalize <- Vectorize(function(v) (v-min(v))/diff(range(v)))
data.frame(lapply(df, normalize))
#    X1  X2
# 1 NaN NaN
# 2 NaN NaN
# 3 NaN NaN
```

Let's leave off the `Vectorize` (and add `na.rm = TRUE` for good measure, in case there are `NA` values in your actual data):

```
normalize = function(v) (v - min(v, na.rm = TRUE)) / diff(range(v, na.rm = TRUE))

data.frame(lapply(df, normalize))
#    X1         X2
# 1 0.0 0.00000000
# 2 0.5 0.05555556
# 3 1.0 1.00000000
```

This works!

---

Note that we could work more with the `scale` function. If you specify `center = min(x)`, then the minimums will be subtracted and you'll get 0s... but then `max(x)` is no longer the correct `scale` factor. We need to use `diff(range())` here, just like in the other methods:

```
# also works
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) scale(
  x, 
  center = min(x, na.rm = TRUE),
  scale = diff(range(x, na.rm = TRUE))
)))
#    X1         X2
# 1 0.0 0.00000000
# 2 0.5 0.05555556
# 3 1.0 1.00000000
```

Comment: fixed! Thank you for the support and thorough explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the data.frame and then normalize it by `lapply`ing the normalizing function to the data set.

Note the square brackets without which `dfout` doesn't keep its tabular shape.

```
normalize <- function(v, na.rm = FALSE) (v - min(v, na.rm = na.rm))/diff(range(v, na.rm = na.rm))

dfout <- Data_profile
dfout[] <- lapply(dfout, normalize)
```

With the data in [Gregor Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74115679/8245406), the result is the following.

```
dfout
#   X1         X2
#1 0.0 0.00000000
#2 0.5 0.05555556
#3 1.0 1.00000000
```